# How to find the limit of $\lim_{n \to +\infty}{n \left(\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^{2n}}$?

Tags: limits

I have literally no idea on how to solve this one
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}{n \left(\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^{2n}}$$

Comment: Hint $\arctan(1/\sqrt{n})\sim1/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$\arctan x = \int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt \le x$$

for all $x\ge 0.$ Thus

$$n\left (\arctan 1/\sqrt n \right)^n \le n\cdot (1/\sqrt n)^n.$$

What do you think?

Comment: So, since the function on the right side of the inequality converges to 0 and the expression on the left is equal or greater, than 0, the expression in the middle also converges to 0. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**just a hint**

Using the fact that
$$\arctan (x)\sim x \;(x\to 0) $$
we have
$$u_n\sim n (n^{-\frac12})^{2n} \;\;(n\to +\infty) $$

$$\sim n^{1-n} \;\; (n\to+\infty) $$

but $$n^{1-n}=e^{n(\frac1n-1)\ln (n)} $$

thus, the limit is $e^{-\infty}= $zero.

Comment: Why is it possible to change $\left(\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt n})\right)^n$ to $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n$? What theorem is used here?

Comment: There is a problem with the equivalent of $\biggl(\arctan\dfrac 1{\sqrt n}\biggr)^{2n}$: the exponent depends on $n$.

Comment: @Bernard In fact $1^\infty $ is indeterminate.

Comment: Yes but  you can solve this limit first taking the logs and proceed backwards using that, if $f(x)-g(x)\to 0$,  then $\mathrm e^{f(x)}\sim\mathrm e^{g(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x^2}(\arctan x)^{2/x^2}
$$
The limit of the logarithm is
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}
2\left(
\frac{\log\arctan x}{x^2}-\log x
\right)=
2\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\log\arctan x-x^2\log x}{x^2}=-\infty
$$
because $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2\log x=0$.

Hence your limit is $0$, because $\lim_{t\to-\infty}e^t=0$.